# Is there a way that can be used to fill a listbox all at once with a list of object based on a specific property?

Tags: c#, winforms

To be more clear, suppose we have a list which contains our processes, and all we want to do is to fill our listbox with the name of those processes.

```
List<Process> latesProcessList ;
```

And now we plan on populating our ListBox, with the items stored inside that array so we would write:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(latesProcessList.ToArray());
```

The problem with the above statement is that, latestProcessList contains objects, and those objects has lots of properties, from which only a handful of them are needed to be displayed in a listbox. 
So what i am asking is , Is there a way that i can use to be able to only fill my listbox with Process names? 
I want the process to be fast, thats why i tried to use AddRange() in first place.
So is there a way to achive such a thing ? if not what is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify about the timer you mentioned below? Are you trying to refresh listbox completely every 1 ms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and use Linq

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(latesProcessList.Select(p => p.ProcessName));
```

Comment: This is inside a timer_tick event which is triggered every 1 millisecond! Doesnt converting a linq method to a normal function each time at runtime make it slow?

Comment: @Hossein how often does this list change?

Comment: Well that depends on the number of processes getting running. After all i am constantly polling, to see if i have a new process and then compare it against a white-list to let it run or terminate it

Comment: @Hossein You can try and benchmark it but I dont see it being too stressful if the List isnt too large